# How to use JSON to export data

Tags: json, mongodb

Thank you in advance for all your support.

I wanted to inquire about using JSON.  I understand that JSON is used as a means to take data from the db and display it on a HTML page (or perhaps even export the data to a csv file).  What I am not understanding is do we use JSON to exports all kinds of data, even sensitive data such as SSN, Username, Password and etc...?   I have done some research and what I am finding is that many articles mention not extract this kind of data but I do not understand why.  My end objective is to build a system where I want to allow my clients to be able to export data from my system to theirs.  I would like to also mention that I am building this using MongoDB.  I'm not sure if this really matters or not, but thought I would mention it.

I am really looking for knowledge here about JSON and how to correctly use it.  I don't need to know how to write JSON or something.

Thanks in advance again.

- AJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, MongoDB uses [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/), not JSON. The MongoDB shell and some drivers abstracts it as JSON to make it more human-readable.

MongoDB has no build-in support for data encryption. That means when you have sensitive information, you should encrypt it before putting it into the database and decrypt it after you retrieve it.